# Get random element from concurrent dictionary c#

Tags: c#, concurrentdictionary

I'm looking for a data structure that is able to handle concurrency well (as removal & add from multiple threads will happen), and that allows me to map quickly (O(1)) from a hashed key to the corresponding object.

I also have to be able to retrieve X elements at random from this data structure.

I started with a Set, but oddly enough there is no ConcurrentSet implementation and I want to retrieve the reference to my object, as I want to do things with it.

I'm currently having a ConcurrentDictionary that maps an int (the hashed value) to the object. This seems to work fine for the first requirements, but this is not convenient at all for picking elements at random. I've thought about converting the values to an array and picking at random from this, but I don't think this would fit in term of complexity and memory.

Is there a way to do this ? Or another approach to this problem that would allow me to have good performances to map objects concurrently and pick some at random ?

Comment: Have you tried ConcurrentBag ??

Comment: I have to be able to remove element from the datastructure

Comment: How about generating a random number (based on the number of items in you dictionary) and using ElementAt to retrieve?

Comment: Pretty sure you can remove an element from it using `TryTake` method

Comment: Also give a Look at F# Concurrency
https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/concurrency-intro/

Comment: Just a fyi, if you do not need the `ISet` specific methods like `IsSupersetOf(` and you only need the `Contains(` check you can easily turn a ConcurrentDictionary in to a ConcurrentSet, just decare the dictionary `ConcurrentDictionary<T,Object>` then any place you call `Add` you just use `null` as the value and anyplace you call `Contains` you call `ContainsKey`

Comment: Do you want to actually remove the randomly selected items at the time that they are randomly selected? Or is item removal done at a different time?

Answer (score 2):

Iterating over the `ConcurrentDictionary` is lock-free and relatively cheap.
I would suggest picking a bunch of random numbers from `0` to `dict.Count - 1`, then iterating with `foreach` or LINQ and retrieving items at these indexes.

But the whole solution depends on the use case. If you rarely update the dictionary, but often read it, you may consider `copy-on-write` semantics which allows operating on a "snapshot" of data: https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/platforms/dotnet/Apache.Ignite.Core/Impl/Common/CopyOnWriteConcurrentDictionary.cs

Comment: As an alternate solution, [ImmutableDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467181(v=vs.111).aspx) built in to .net has copy on write semantics too